# Render Array in Random Order React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a React Js Beginner. I'm creating a MCQ Portal and wanted to display mcqs options in random order.

1. Right Now I'm using `.js` file for data But later planning to shift
   to MongoDB.
2. I'm using URL Parameter to retrieve specific MCQ.  Is
   there a way to shuffle array?

Here's the code

```
import React from 'react';
import mcqContent from './mcq-content';
const MCQPage = ({match}) =>{
    const reqUrl = match.params.name;
    const mcqData = mcqContent.find(mcqData => mcqData.m_slug === reqUrl);
    const correctMcq = mcqData.m_alternatives[0];
    function shuffle(array) {
        let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
      
        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (currentIndex !== 0) {
      
          // Pick a remaining element...
          randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
          currentIndex--;
      
          // And swap it with the current element.
          [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
            array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
        }
      
        return array;
      }
    const optionsArray = mcqData.m_alternatives
    const shuffledArray = shuffle(optionsArray)
    return (
    <>
        <h1>{mcqData.m_title}</h1><br/>
        <h3>{mcqData.m_question}</h3>
        {shuffledArray.map((paragraph, key) => (
            <p key={key}>{paragraph}</p>
            ))}
        <h4>Answer: {correctMcq}</h4>
    </>
    );
};
export default MCQPage;
```

Here's the MCQ Content File

```
const mcqs = [
    {
        "_id":1,
        "m_title":"Which company is the most valueable in the world?",
        "m_slug":"which-company-is-the-most-valueable",
        "m_question":"Which company is the most valueable in the world?",
        "m_alternatives":["Apple","Google","Microsoft"],
        "m_number":"Gen-Know-1",
        "m_subject":"General Knowledge",
    },  
];

export default mcqs;
```

Comment: is there another page that has the code you wnat to use to navigate them to randomly?

Comment: No, Is it needed? I was wondering is there a function to shuffle array?

Comment: Check out this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: It's working But now correct option also changes every time. I have edit the code. Please guide me.

Comment: i think you should ask a new question